# How do I iterate through the first object in the list ONLY in play 1.2.7 application

Tags: java, playframework

For my play 1.2.7 application I had to create a hashmap in a hashmap struct, called `totalNumberAcrossExamTypesAndDates`, that holds the result set from a complex query to postgres database (uses subqueries and aggregate functions, so can NO use entity properties to manipulate the content), and now am having trouble iterating through the FIRST object in that monster. Why only the first object? Because the keys are the same for all objects `markerName`. The ultimate goal is to get a date/markerName/valueForThisMarkerAndDate report.

```
        date1  date2
```

markerName1   X      Y
markerName2   W      Q

I am looking for something that would work like this

```
#{list items:totalNumberAcrossExamTypesAndDates.get(0) as:'firstObject'}
  <td>${firstObject.key}</td>   
#{/list}
```

How do I do it? Any pointers are welcome.

If it makes it any clearer here is what `totalNumberAcrossExamTypesAndDates` actually is

`Map<Date, HashMap<String, Integer>>`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access to the first object, you don't need any iteration. Just use

```
${totalNumberAcrossExamTypesAndDates.entrySet()[0].key}
```

Note that, unless the map is a TreeMap or a SortedMap, accessing its first entry doesn't make much sense, since the order of entries in a map is undefined.

If I didn't understabd correctly, and the object is in fact a collection and not a map, then you just need

```
${totalNumberAcrossExamTypesAndDates[0].key}
```

Comment: What do you mean by collection? List?

Comment: List, or Set, or any class implementing java.util.Collection